# ASP.NET MVC : how to check if the image exist in other site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have a site where users can post links with images from another websites. Problem is some times this links a broken and don't contain an image, and I see a broken image instead of image on my web site.

How can I check does the link to other website contains an image or not?

[image]

Comment: I have image link that ends with ... .png and it is opened brocken. If there a way to cheack such cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a GET request to the image url, if the response status code is 200 then the image was found, if 404 not found.

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "link-to-image");
var response = httpClient.Send(request); // Exist SendAsync version
var statusCode = response.StatusCode; // 200 image exist, 404 not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess this code can help. It's a bit harder than the previous author's one, sorry

```
string imageUrl = "http://example.com/image.jpg";
        
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
request.Method = "HEAD";
    
   using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //Image exists
        }
        else
        {
            //Image does not exist
        }
    }
```